# Is aggregate function available in Primefaces?

Tags: primefaces, aggregate-functions, aggregation-framework

I want to do aggregation from the datatable using Primefaces. But I can't find any resources for this. Anyone know about this?

Comment: There isn't an aggregation framework for Datatable. You can only sort the result clicking in the table's header. You have to build your result object which is used by datatable in the `value` attribute.

Comment: @Miguel Oh!I see! Thanks for your answer! Can you post this as an answer?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an aggregation framework for Datatable. You can only sort the result clicking in the table's header. You have to build your result object which is used by datatable in the `value` attribute.